# Generate shared secret using private key from string type

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I have very little knowledge in Cryptology, please excuse if this is a silly question.

I want to generate ECDH shared secret using private key and peer public key in Java.
I am trying to follow some sources on the internet and what is given here : http://dev.coova.org/svn/cjradius/trunk/ssl/src/main/java/net/jradius/ssl/ECDHCrypt.java

The code which I have, generates public and private key based on user credentials:

```
import com.google.bitcoin.bouncycastle.asn1.sec.SECNamedCurves;
import com.google.bitcoin.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import com.google.bitcoin.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
import com.google.bitcoin.core.Utils

public String ecdaPrivate(String hexstring) {  // The hexstring is the hex value   generated based on username and password

    byte[] hexBytes = new byte[32];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < hexstring.length(); i++, j++) {
        String pairStr = hexstring.substring(i, i + 2);
        int value = Integer.parseInt(pairStr, 16);
        hexBytes[j] = (byte) (value & 0xFF);

        i++;
    }

    char[] hexChars = new char[hexBytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < hexBytes.length; j++) {
        int v = hexBytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }

    return new String(hexChars);
}


public String getPublicKey(String privateKey) {
    BigInteger privKey = new BigInteger(privateKey, 16);
    X9ECParameters ecp = SECNamedCurves.getByName("secp256k1");
    ECPoint curvePt = ecp.getG().multiply(privKey);
    BigInteger x = curvePt.getX().toBigInteger();
    BigInteger y = curvePt.getY().toBigInteger();
    byte[] xBytes = this.removeSignByte(x.toByteArray());
    byte[] yBytes = this.removeSignByte(y.toByteArray());
    byte[] pubKeyBytes = new byte[65];
    pubKeyBytes[0] = new Byte("04");
    System.arraycopy(xBytes, 0, pubKeyBytes, 1, xBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(yBytes, 0, pubKeyBytes, 33, yBytes.length);
    return this.bytesToHex(pubKeyBytes);
}
```

These keys are in String type.
The problem is that most of the sources from Internet uses Privatekey and PublicKey types (java.security.PrivateKey), however the private key what I have is in the form of string type. 
Question is how do I convert a string to private key/public key object type.

Comment: The real question is why did you convert the keys to String in the first place. They originate as PublicKey/PrivateKey or byte[] arrays. Leave them that way. String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: @EJP I have updated the question with the code I am using to generate the keys. This was returning the right keys,so I used it. Not sure if there is something equivalent to above logic.

Comment: Well it's exactly as I said. You already had the bytes, and you transformed them into strings. Solution: don't do that. Then, use a KeyFactory to recreate the PublicKey and PrivateKey from the byte arrays.